# C# Get child window titles of my process

Tags: c#, process, get, window

ive got this simple question (I want to get all(except the main) Window titles of my process), ive googled and tryed alot but nothing really worked for me. Im not very advanced with this stuff, would be nice if you can give me a little exsample.

thanks in advance

edit: its a third party process

Comment: Is this a WPF or WinForms application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are developing a windows desktop application, so you can use that code:

```
FormCollection forms = Application.OpenForms;
List<string> titleList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in forms)
{
    Form form = item as Form;
    if (form == null || form.Equals(this))
        continue;
    else
        titleList.Add(form.Text);
}
```

The result will be in the "titleList" variable.

Comment: its a third party process

Comment: You mean, you are launching an exe inside from your program and you want that exe's title? If this is the case, which method are you using to launch third party process? ex: Process.Start("c:\test.exe");

Comment: Well i start a exe/process inside my code (x: Process.Start("c:\test.exe"); ) and i want to monitor what windows this process opens. ex: if process opens a window called (connection lost) kill that process

Comment: I could only get a main window name just like that: string title = Process.Start("c:\test.exe").MainWindowTitle; Maybe that link can help you, at least give an idea: http://www.tcx.be/blog/2006/list-open-windows/

Comment: thanks thats what i wanted now i just have to check the parent of the window :)